# contar texto igual do banco de dados em php

Tags: php, html, mysql, query

Bom dia, 
a minha dúvida é a seguinte: no meu caso eu tenho uma tabela no banco de dados que permite avaliar um serviço, a classificação é feita por cores "vermelho, amarelo e verde", ou seja o tipo é `text`. 
O que eu queria é fazer uma `query` em `php` que permite contar quantos "verdes", "amarelos" e "vermelhos" estão inseridos. 
**Esta é a tabela:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu pretendo é por exemplo **no dia 06-06 houve 3 verdes, 2 amarelos e 1 vermelho**, e **no dia 07-06 houve 1 verde**. Em questão à data, eu tenho um calendário que fiz com jquery e Ajax. 
Eu experimentei algo assim

```
$verificar=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT classificacao, count(classificacao) from questionario GROUP by classificacao");

    while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($verificar)) {
        if($linha['classificacao'] == 'vermelho')
        {
            $output.='<td style="background-color:#ff6666; text-align: center; padding: 8px; font-weight: bold;">'.$linha['classificacao'].'</td>';
        } 
        elseif($linha['classificacao'] == 'amarelo')
        {
            $output.='<td style="background-color:#ffff80; text-align: center; padding: 8px; font-weight: bold;">'.$linha['classificacao'].'</td>';
        } 
        elseif($linha['classificacao'] == 'verde')
        {
            $output.='<td style="background-color:#80ff80; text-align: center; padding: 8px; font-weight: bold;">'.$linha['classificacao'].'</td>';
        }
        $output.='  
        </tr>  
        ';  
    }
```

Porém não retorna nenhum valor, alguém pode me indicar o que está errado?Obrigada desde já quem puder ajudar!

Comment: Essa coluna classificação, você grava o nome da cor ou a cor em Hexadecimal?

Comment: Nome da cor Rafa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ana, primeiramente te aconselho a usar PDO. Modifiquei um pouco seu sql e php da uma olhada.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=BASE", "USUARIO", "SENHA");

try {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(cod) as total, classificacao from questionario group by classificacao");
  $stmt->execute();
  $output = '';
  while ($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $output.='<tr> ';
    if($linha['classificacao'] == 'vermelho')
    {
      $output.='<td style="background-color:#ff6666; text-align: center; padding: 8px; font-weight: bold;">'.$linha['classificacao']." = ".$linha['total'].'</td>';
    }
    elseif($linha['classificacao'] == 'amarelo')
    {
      $output.='<td style="background-color:#ffff80; text-align: center; padding: 8px; font-weight: bold;">'.$linha['classificacao']." = ".$linha['total'].'</td>';
    }
    elseif($linha['classificacao'] == 'verde')
    {
      $output.='<td style="background-color:#80ff80; text-align: center; padding: 8px; font-weight: bold;">'.$linha['classificacao']." = ".$linha['total'].'</td>';
    }
    $output.='</tr> ';

  }
  echo $output;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "<script>alert(\"Ocorreu um erro durante a listagem ".$e."\");</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Rafa tentei como disseste, mas ele repete várias vezes as linhas, e eu queria q aparecesse somente 3 (uma para cada cor), mas obrigada, já é meio caminho andado

Comment: Ana, da uma conferidinha, para mim retornou AMARELO = 1 VERDE = 5 VERMELHO = 3

Comment: Tentei sumular teu banco, você esta usando qual coluna no COUNT?

Comment: Estou a utilizar pergunta_id, é a chave primária da tabela, portanto calculei que o seu "cod" fosse isso! Vou tentar novamente Rafa! Obrigada

Comment: Oi. Vi melhor e não tinha reparado que o grupo seria (dia, cor), desta forma a query tem de ser : **SELECT classificacao, data, count(classificacao) from questionario GROUP by classificacao, data**, isto contará o numero de verdes/vermelhos/amarelos pelo par (cor, dia).

Comment: vc precisa separar por dia e por cor certo? por ex: dia 06/06/18 AMARELO = 1 VERDE = 5 VERMELHO = 3  - dia 07/06/18 AMARELO =5 VERDE = 2 VERMELHO = 1 ?

Comment: Rafa muito obrigada, funcionou, eu tinha um while a mais era isso! Acerca sobre os dias, de acordo com o exemplo que mostrei na minha questão seria **dia 07-07-2018 verde=1** (pois só houve uma `qualificação` nesse dia, mas disso eu já tratei, eu utilizei um between!

Comment: Legal Ana. Sucesso no projeto.

Answer (score 1):

)

Parece-me que a query não está de acordo com os ifs seguintes, pois foram dados alias às colunas em vez de manter a coluna como "classificação" e valores "verde", "amarelo", "vermelho".

O select a usar deve ser algo do tipo:

```
select classificacao, count(*) from questionario group by classificacao
```

para que os ifs seguintes funcionem

Comment: Ana, eu experimentei o mesmo agora, usando essa query, mas nao está dando na mesma, ele apenas repete várias vezes a palavra da cor, não retorna o número de vezes que a cor aparece

Comment: Voce quer o numero de cores por dia?

Comment: Wees sim, mas disso eu já tratei, por isso a única coisa que preciso é que mostre as vezes que "vermelho" aparece etc,... O output seria simplesmente 3 linhas a dizer **vermelho:1 verde: 4 amarelo: 2**

Comment: @Ana, 
a query que coloquei aqui retorna linhas do tipo [cor, #ocorrencias]
o php apresentado inicialmente só iria apresentar 3 linhas com as respectivas cores, nao utilizaria o count da query, já utilizado no php apresentado no comentário seguinte.

Comment: Ana obrigada, a query é praticamente isso sim que eu precisava!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja isso aqui então @Ana:

```
$verificar=mysqli_query($link,"
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN classificacao = 'verde' THEN classificacao END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN classificacao = 'vermelho' THEN classificacao END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN classificacao = 'amarelo' THEN classificacao END)
    FROM questionario        
");
```

Esses `COUNT()` vão contar as cores separadas, ai vc adapta ao seu código atual.

Comment: Wees era o que eu tinha antes no meu código, só que eu editei a pergunta, ele simplesmente não mostra o resultado

Answer (score -2):

Olá

use

```
$verificar=mysqli_query($link,"
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN classificacao = 'verde' THEN classificacao END) as vermelho,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN classificacao = 'vermelho' THEN classificacao END) as vermelho,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN classificacao = 'amarelo' THEN classificacao END) as amarelo
FROM questionario
```

");

e na demonstração use por exemplo

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($verificar);
echo $row['amarelo'];
```

assim irá funcionar.

Comment: Porque votaram ruim? Qual erro no meu codigo? Sendo que no meu funcionou perfeitamente e ainda ajudei!