# verificar diferença entre valores com php

Tags: php, mysql

Necessitava de ajuda para verificar se a quantidade escolhida pelo cliente é diferente do stock existente

Código que estou a utilizar

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pap') or die (mysqli_error ());

$strSQL1 = "SELECT 'QuantidadeProduto' FROM `produtos` WHERE `Id_Produto`=1";

$rs1 = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL1);



  if(isset($_POST['verifica1'])){
    $quantiade = $_POST['quantidade'];
  }

  if($quantiade>$rs1){
    echo ("inferiror");
  }
  elseif ($quantiade<$rs1){
    echo("Falta stock");
  }
```

e está me a dar os seguintes erros

> Warning: Use of undefined constant quantiade - assumed 'quantiade' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 635
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant quantiade - assumed 'quantiade' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 638

Comment: falta-te o $ atrás da quantidade

Comment: dá erro na mesma por isso tentei sem. dá o seguinte erro Notice: Undefined variable: quantiade in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 635

Comment: na bd tens o campo "quantidade" correto ?

Comment: esse campo quantidade é o numero de itens que é indicado por um select. Na base de dados o campo chama-se QuantidadeProduto

Comment: Seu erro pode ser porque a variável `$_POST['quantidade']` não retorna nada, nesse caso sua variável `$quantiade` nem será declarada.

Comment: mas ele retorna o valor certo, ou seja a variável é declarada

Comment: se tu dá um echo na $rs1, ele traz o que?

Comment: Modifica $quantiade = $_POST['quantidade']; para $quantiade = $_POST['QuantidadeProduto'];

Comment: @Rafa dá erro na mesma -> Notice: Undefined index: QuantidadeProduto in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 634
1Falta stockstdClass Object ( [name] => QuantidadeProduto [orgname] => [table] => [orgtable] => [def] => [db] => [catalog] => def [max_length] => 17 [length] => 17 [charsetnr] => 8 [flags] => 1 [type] => 253 [decimals] => 31 )

Comment: Confere minha reposta nesse caso, usa PDO, você pode se basear nesse exemplo para comparar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/contar-texto-igual-do-banco-de-dados-em-php

Comment: Gente o erro não é porque quantidade está escrito errado??? "quan**tia**de"

Comment: Não @LeandroAngelo tu dás o nome à variavel que tu queres

Answer (score 2):

O erro, conforme já dito da falta do `$`, é que você não está fazendo o fetch do resultado da query:

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pap') or die (mysqli_error ());

$strSQL1 = "SELECT 'QuantidadeProduto' FROM `produtos` WHERE `Id_Produto`=1";

$rs1 = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL1);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs1)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0]);
    }
```

Comment: já foi colocado o $ no código e no exemplo em cima também

Comment: e tu testou com o fetch que coloquei?

Comment: dá o seguinte erro --> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 630
QuantidadeProduto () . Na linha 630 está o printf

Comment: Corrigi a resposta.

Comment: dá o seguinte erro : Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 630

Comment: e depois de clicar para confirmar dá este : Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 630
stdClass Object ( [name] => QuantidadeProduto [orgname] => [table] => [orgtable] => [def] => [db] => [catalog] => def [max_length] => 17 [length] => 17 [charsetnr] => 8 [flags] => 1 [type] => 253 [decimals] => 31 )

Answer (score 0):

Duas coisas estão erradas ou incompletas no seu código.

A primeira é que falta $ antes da variável quantiade em duas linhas. E a segunda é que dessa forma não garante que a variável `$quantiade` será sempre declarada.

Você pode corrigir da seguinte forma:

```
if(isset($_POST['verifica1'])){
    $quantiade = $_POST['quantidade'];
}else{
    $quantiade = 0; // um exemplo, você pode colocar outro valor como padrão
}

if($quantiade>$rs1){
    echo ("inferiror");
}
elseif ($quantiade<$rs1){
    echo("Falta stock");
}
```

Comment: como foi comentado em cima o "$" tinha sido tirado mas mesmo com ele dá o erro. Obrigado pelo alerta para a verificação :)

Comment: Entendo, mas precisa de corrigir os isso também, além do else no isset post para funcionar :)

Comment: sim já corrigi , mas mesmo assim dá erro

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro agora?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: quantidade in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 636 - verificação para ver o que recebe, depois de clicar no botao funciona normalmente

Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 639

Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\pagina_produto.php on line 643

Comment: Isso indica que o `$_POST['quantidade']` não existe, já o segundo erro indica que você não pode fazer comparações com a variável `$rs1` como se fosse um inteiro, pois ela não é. Dê um print_r nela para ver o formato da variável, provavelmente é um objeto ou array.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78576/discussion-between-jose-gomes-and-david-alves).